# Can NSManagedObject conform to NSCoding

Tags: ios, core-data, nscoder

I need to transfer a single object across device. Right now I am converting my NSManagedObject to a dictionary , archiving it and sending as NSData. Upon receiving I am unarchiving it. But I would really like to transfer the NSManagedObject itself by archiving and unarchiving instead of creating an intermediate data object.

```
@interface Test : NSManagedObject<NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@end

@implementation Test
@dynamic title;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.title = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"]; //<CRASH
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
}
@end


NSData *archivedObjects = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:testObj];
NSData *objectsData = archivedObjects;
if ([objectsData length] > 0) {
    NSArray *objects = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:objectsData];
}
```

The problem with the above code is. It crashes at `self.title` in `initWithCoder` saying unrecognized selector sent to instance.

- Why is `title` not being recognized as a selector.
- Should unarchive use a nil managed object context somehow before creating the object in `initWithCoder`?
- Do i need to override `copyWithZone`?

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html): ` If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet below should do the trick. The main difference is to call `super initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test" inManagedObjectContext:<YourContext>];

   self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
   NSArray * attributeNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.entity.attributesByName.allKeys];

   for (NSString * attributeName in attributeNameArray) {
        [self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:attributeName] forKey:attributeName];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Above snippet will handle only the attributes, no relationships. Dealing with relationships as `NSManagedObjectID` using `NSCoding` is horrible. If you do need to bring relationships across consider introducing an extra attribute to match the two (or many) entities when decoding.

#### how to obtain `<YourContext>`

(based on a now unavailable post by Sam Soffes, code taken from https://gist.github.com/soffes/317794#file-ssmanagedobject-m)

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)mainContext {
     AppDelegate *appDelegate = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate];
return [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
}
```

Note: replace `<YourContext>` in the first snippet with `mainContext`

Comment: The link on how to obtain <YourContext> is broken. Can you update it?

Comment: The original site is offline, but I found an a old gist and have copied the code from there. I hope this helps

Comment: Is managed context intentionally nil in this line?

`self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];`

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `NSManagedObject` does not conform to `NSCoding`. You could try to make a custom managed object subclass conform, but it would be a dicey proposition at best. An `NSManagedObject` must have a related `NSManagedObjectID`. And, you don't get to assign the object ID-- that happens automatically when the object is created. Even if you made your subclass conform to `NSCoding`, you'd have to find a way to unarchive the object while also allowing the local managed object context to assign an object ID.

And even that ignores the question of how you'd handle relationships on your managed objects.

Converting to/from an `NSDictionary` is really a much better approach. But you can't just unarchive the data and be finished. On the receiving end, you need to create a new managed object instance and set its attribute values from the dictionary. It *might* be possible to get your approach to work, but by the time you're done it will be more work and more code than if you just used an `NSDictionary`.

Seriously: `NSCoding`, `initWithCoder:`, `copyWithZone:`, etc, are a really bad idea for the problem you're trying to solve. `NSCoding` is nice for many situations but it's not appropriate here.

Comment: agreed that NSCoding on a NSManagedObject is a bad idea. generic way to transfer/serialize a NSManagedObject should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously the unarchiver. In the end there is no way to use both `initWithEntity:` and `initWithCoder:` in the same object. However, I suspect that with some trickery you may be able to make this work. For instance, implement `initWithCoder:` as you have done, and in that create another managed object with `initWithEntity:` (this means you will need unmanaged ivars that can hold such a reference. Implement `forwardingTargetForSelector:`, and if the object is the one being created using `initWithCoder:`, forward it to the shadow object you created with `initWithEntity:` (otherwise, forward that selector to super). When the object is decoded fully, then ask it for the real managed object, and you're done.

NOTE: I have not done this but have had great success with `forwardingTargetForSelector:`.