# CoreData: Error by decode data from Context/Store NSData -> NSArray

Tags: core-data, ios6

i'm new in iOS-Development area and trying now to update an existing App to iOS 6.1 from iOS4.

> > > get Data from Store to show in NewsPageView : UIViewController

```
NewsPageView.m

#import "NewsPageView.h"

@interface NewsPageView ()

@end

@implementation NewsPageView

@synthesize newsDetailsView,
            newsTableView,
            newsHeaderText
;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    /*
     * Get managedObjectContext and List of News over AppDelegate
     */
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    //Setting self.managedObjectContext
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

    // Fetching Records from the data base to show in the table
    self.listOfNews = [[appDelegate getDataFromStore:self]copy];

    //
    NSLog(@"Data from Store in NewsPageView: %@",self.listOfNews.description);
}
```

> > > try to set/write data into Context

```
-(void) setDataToStore
{

    NSLog(@"Trying to write News in Store");

    News *newNews = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    newNews.newsId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:508];
    newNews.title = @"Some Title";
    newNews.content = @"Some content";
    newNews.detailsUrl = @"www.someURL.de";
    newNews.date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    newNews.dateTs = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:138114787];
    newNews.primaryCat = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:0];

    //make Categorien...
    NewsCategorien *cat1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewsCategorien" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    cat1.catId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:1];
    cat1.name = @"Windows";
    cat1.news = newNews;

    NewsCategorien *cat2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewsCategorien" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    cat2.catId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:2];
    cat2.name = @"Linux";
    cat2.news = newNews;

    NewsCategorien *cat3 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewsCategorien" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    cat3.catId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:3];
    cat3.name = @"Apple";
    cat3.news = newNews;

    NewsCategorien *cat5 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewsCategorien" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    cat5.catId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:5];
    cat5.name = @"Smartphone";
    cat5.news = newNews;

    newNews.isNews = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];

    NSArray *catListe = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cat1,cat2,cat3,cat5, nil];


//    //saving cat by converting Cat. objects
//    newNews.categories = catListe;

    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    NSLog(@"Saving ok!");
}
```

> > > try to get Data from Context

```
- (NSArray *)getDataFromStore:(id)sender
{
    // initializing NSFetchRequest
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSArray *fetchedData;

    //get Data für NewsTable View
    if([sender isKindOfClass:[NewsPageView class]]){

        //Setting Entity to be Queried
        fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        NSError* error;

//Point of Error by debugging!!!
        //return list of News
        fetchedData = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    }

    //print fetched Data
    for (News *news in fetchedData) {
        NSLog(@"News:%@", news.description);
    }

    // Returning Fetched News
    return fetchedData;
}
```

> > > Classes

```
News.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class NewsCategorien;

@interface News : NSManagedObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, retain) id categories;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * content;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * dateTs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * detailsUrl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isNews;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * newsId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * primaryCat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *categorie;


//have to be implement...
//to work with NSKeyedArchiver by serialising Objects
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;

//to work with NSKeyedUnarchiver by deserialising Objects
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

@end

@interface News (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCategorieObject:(NewsCategorien *)value;
- (void)removeCategorieObject:(NewsCategorien *)value;
- (void)addCategorie:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCategorie:(NSSet *)values;

@end

/*
 * News Transformer NSArray -> NSData and reverse
 * Model: News should have Attribut type of Transformable and have name NewsTrasformer
 */

@interface NewsTransformer : NSValueTransformer

@end

News.m
#import "News.h"
#import "NewsCategorien.h"


@implementation News

@dynamic categories;
@dynamic content;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic dateTs;
@dynamic detailsUrl;
@dynamic isNews;
@dynamic newsId;
@dynamic primaryCat;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic categorie;

//tell the archiver how to transform the serialized representation into a new object -> deserialize Objects!
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.categories = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"categories"];
        self.content = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"content"];
        self.date = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"];
        self.dateTs = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dateTs"];
        self.detailsUrl = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"detailsUrl"];
        self.isNews = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"isNews"];
        self.newsId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"newsId"];
        self.primaryCat = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"primaryCat"];
        self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.categorie = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"categorie"];
    }

    NSLog(@"<<<< ---- Deserialize Object News (Init With Code) --->");

    return self;
}

//tell the archiver how to serialize your object into bytes -> serialize Objects!
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.categories forKey:@"categories"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.content forKey:@"content"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.date forKey:@"date"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.dateTs forKey:@"dateTs"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.detailsUrl forKey:@"detailsUrl"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.isNews forKey:@"isNews"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.newsId forKey:@"newsId"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.primaryCat forKey:@"primaryCat"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.categorie forKey:@"categorie"];

    NSLog(@"<<<< ---- Serialize Object News (encode With Coder) --->");
}

@end

//
@implementation NewsTransformer

//Return the Class for Forwarding Transformation
+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSArray class];
}

+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

// converts the NSArray into NSData using NSKeyedArchiver
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    NSLog(@"Transformer: NSArray -> NSData");
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:value];
}

// by default raises an exception if +allowsReverseTransformation returns NO and otherwise invokes transformedValue:
//converts NSData to an NSArray using NSKeyedUnarchiver
- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    NSLog(@"Transformer: NSData -> NSArray");
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
}

@end

NewsCategorien.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class News;

@interface NewsCategorien : NSManagedObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * catId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) News *news;

//for serializing of objects have to be implement...
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;

//for serializing of objects have to be implement...
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

@end


NewsCategorien.m

#import "NewsCategorien.h"
#import "News.h"


@implementation NewsCategorien

@dynamic catId;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic news;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.catId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"catId"];
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
        self.news = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"news"];
    }

    NSLog(@"<<<< ---- Deserialize Object Categorie ---> : %@",self.description);

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.catId forKey:@"catId"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.news forKey:@"news"];

    NSLog(@"<<<< ---- Serialize Object Categorie ---> %@",self.description);
}

@end
```

> > > Model
> > >       News
> > >       Attribute: categorien Type: Transformable Name: NewsTransformer

Relationchip one-to-more
categorien Des. NewsCategorien Inverse news

Categorien
Att. catId String
Att. name  Interger16

> > > My problem:
> > >       1. writing data to the context - OK
> > >       2.when i'm trying to get data from the context(NSData->NSArray) i get following error:
> > >
> > > Error

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NewsCategorien' 
2013-11-20 16:03:19.204 securityNews[19458:c07] -[NewsCategorien setCatId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8173740
2013-11-20 16:03:19.205 securityNews[19458:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NewsCategorien setCatId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8173740'
```

any idea what i doing wrong??

Comment: The first error comes from the way you are using this class-- specifically, the code that creates new instances of `NewsCategorien`. What does that code look like?

Comment: Hey Tom,thanks for help me!
I just posted additional code what are you asking me for. 
I hope it will helps...
This is the first test by writing some data into Context,original data i will get over JSON..

Comment: Is that the only place where you create a `NewsCategorien`? Because the error message suggests that you're doing it differently somewhere else.

Comment: Yes this is the only place!I posted a code on witch place i make instance of AppDelegate to get data by calling "getDataFromStore" method.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [Can NSManagedObject conform to NSCoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441587/can-nsmanagedobject-conform-to-nscoding)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is almost certainly due to your implementation of `initWithCoder:`, specifically this line:

```
if (self = [super init]) {
```

You can't create a managed object using `init`. You must use the designated initializer `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. Or you can use `NSEntityDescription`'s method `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`. But using `init` is right out, and doing so will cause a `Failed to call designated initializer` error.

This means that your `initWithCoder` needs to be able to find a managed object context. How you do that depends on your app's structure and where you are creating contexts. If your app delegate has a context object and that's the one you want to use, you could look it up from there. If it's some other context, you'll have to get it from somewhere else. You have a couple of versions of `initWithCoder` and they both have this problem.

The second error is a side-effect of the first error. In `initWithCoder` you do this:

```
if (self = [super init]) {
    self.catId = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"catId"];
    ....
```

But since `[super init]` doesn't work, you're getting back a bogus object that doesn't know what `catId` is. Then you try to set `catId` and it fails. Fix the first error and the second error will disappear.

Comment: Hey Tom,thx for your answer.
It was really stupid from me to use "if (self = [super init]) {" on this place!I knew that i had to use NSEntityDescription(for example) but on this place it was my logical mistake!
I will try to fix it...Thank you very much!