# Convert Managed Object to Data object

Tags: ios, core-data

How do I convert my `NSManagedObject` to `NSData` object?

I'm new to Core Data and the Multipeer Connectivity Framework.

I need to transfer data between 2 devices via the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html). I understand that I cannot simply transfer via MPC since it requires an NSData object.

Are there any third-party libraries that provides such function?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16445901/730701

Answer (score 2):

I think `NSCoding` is not such a good idea here. The reason is that the objects will not be the same on two different devices due to their internal managed object IDs as well as a myriad of other possible problems that can occur in unexpected syncing scenarios.

I would strongly recommend to take the trouble and convert your object into a `NSDictionary` type and then use the standard `NSData` APIs on the dictionary (or an array of dictionaries).

Answer (score 0):

try like this
You should   use NSCoding protocol, then you can encode your object to NSData. Again If you want decode your original object use NSKeyedUnarchiver.

in .h

```
@interface Testting : NSManagedObject<NSCoding>
```

and this in .m

```
  NSData *data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:hereyourObject];
```

//get your original object

```
Testting *Obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Comment: That's not going to work because `NSManagedObject` does not conform to `NSCoding`. If you create a managed object subclass as @Sanjay describes in his answer, it might work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSCoding protocol. Using NSKeyedAchiever you can encode your object to NSData. Again If you want decode your original object use NSKeyedUnarchiver.

```
@interface Test : NSManagedObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@end

@implementation Test
@dynamic title;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    NSEntityDescription *entity = 
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Test"  inManagedObjectContext:<YourContext>];

    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
    NSArray * attributeNameArray = 
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.entity.attributesByName.allKeys];

    for (NSString * attributeName in attributeNameArray) {
        [self setValue:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:attributeName] forKey:attributeName];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:self.title forKey:@"title"];
}
@end

//converting to NSData
NSData *archivedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:testObj];

//get your original object
Test *testObj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedObject];
```